# Strange titles appear while in recovery mode

Tags: boot

Ububntu wasnt starting, only blank screen was seeable. I tried recovery mode, and then all sort of command lines were drawn diagonally from the upper left direction to the down right corner. Was very strange. I attached a picture.
Pls any suggestion is appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hapcq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal, nothing to worry about. It happens simply because recovery mode runs `dialog` window directly from the top terminal level, so all the kernel messages are directly shown on your screen, interfering with the dialog window. And yes, it's sometimes annoying, but hey - it's recovery mode, not the ordinary environment you will be working on daily basis.

Comment: So its not the hackers' alliance trying to take over on my hidden stuff?

Comment: Nor dread dragons. You can carry on with browsing funny cats on the Internet.

Comment: Sir, yes, sir! This must be at least 15 chracters long